# Using Jquery to pull Wordpress post feed into static page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, feed

Just like using the many twitter or facebook widgets out there that pull the feed and display it in a nice widget, I want to create a "widget" that pulls a feed from a wordpress blog that I have, and displays it on a static, non-wordpress page. Before I try getting my hands dirty with jquery, do you know if there is any pre-existing code or plugins out there that I can use?

Comment: See my answer below. In my personal opinion, though, we are putting way too much strain on clients' machines with stuff like this - it's the reason why you can't use a modern web user interface with a machine that has a few years on its back anymore. Getting such data on the server side is usually easy, faster, and more reliable. My 2 cents.

Comment: I completely agree, but when a client requests a feed-heavy homepage,I just follow orders!